# How to export react-bootstrap-table-2 data to excel?

Tags: excel, file, export, react-bootstrap

I am using the react-bootstrap-table-next in my application. I must export data into excel. Is there a way to do? I am using react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit and was able to export only into CSV format. Can anyone help me how to export into excel ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using

```
     <ToolkitProvider
              keyField="id"
              data={products}
              columns={columns}
              search
              exportCSV={{
                fileName: "file.csv",
              }}
            >
```

This has worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try React's package:

Like: Export to Excel [react-html-table-to-excel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-table-to-excel)

Also, you can take help from this [tutorial](https://blog.bitsrc.io/exporting-data-to-excel-with-react-6943d7775a92) on how to export data to excel

Comment: Data is coming from api and I am using Bootstrap table . In that case I can't use this.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/basic-export-csv.html) is the reference for this question:

```
import ToolkitProvider, { CSVExport } from 'react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit';

const { ExportCSVButton } = CSVExport;

<ToolkitProvider
  keyField="id"
  data={ products }
  columns={ columns }
  exportCSV
>
  {
    props => (
      <div>
        <ExportCSVButton { ...props.csvProps }>Export CSV!!</ExportCSVButton>
        <hr />
        <BootstrapTable { ...props.baseProps } />
      </div>
    )
  }
</ToolkitProvider>
```